# Find the CI for a given interval of HDI in R?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I'm looking for a method to calculate the value of the CI for a given a range around the mode.  For example, if my mode (or value with highest KDE) is 50 and I establish an acceptable range of 10 around the mode, what is my equivalent CI?

I've been successful with following the HDI content from https://rdrr.io/cran/HDInterval/man/hdi.html to find the range based on a given CI, but I'm attempting to the reverse the process.  Sample code copied from site to this post for convenience of testing with data:

```
# for a vector:
tst <- rgamma(1e5, 2.5, 2)
hdi(tst)
hdi(tst, credMass=0.8)
# For comparison, the symmetrical 80% CrI:
quantile(tst, c(0.1,0.9))

# for a density:
dens <- density(tst)
hdi(dens, credMass=0.8)
```

My brute-force method would consider something like calculating the difference between the upper/lower values across different CI input until I find a the maximum CI for a given delta between upper and lower.  I'm sure there's a better way?

The goal of this is to compare how the CI changes across different datasets following the same range of values.  Data is often multimodal and trying to avoid constraints of fitting to a distribution.

Comment: There's no way to tell unless you specify a statistical distribution. This is more appropriate at CrossValidated.com. In your case you could bootstrap the answer for the gamma distribution. If you allow multimodal distributions, I'll bet the answer is "you cannot".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work as the brute-force approach:

```
      buffer <- 100
      ci_x <- 1
      ci_hdi = NULL
      while (buffer > 10){
        ci_hdi <- ci(data$x, method = "HDI", ci = ((100-ci_x)/100))
        buffer = ci_hdi$CI_high - ci_hdi$CI_low
        ci_x = ci_x+1
      }
      print(buf)
```

Basically, it counts through values until I find a buffer (range of acceptable values) that meets criteria (e.g. 10) and then reports what CI (100-ci_x) meets this condition.  Functions well in initial tests where I see large CI value on tight distribution, and then something closer to 50's with a volatile distribution.